# Sort an Array of Objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array, with two properties in each element:

```
var player = [{uid: 15, order: 567}, 
              {uid: 4, order: 789}, 
              {uid: 27, order: 123}, 
              {uid: 1, order: 654}];
```

I want to sort the array ascending by the order property.  So the result would be:

```
player = [{uid: 27, order: 123},
          {uid: 15, order: 567},
          {uid: 1, order: 654},
          {uid: 4, order: 789}];
```

Comment: Yeah that is the same question

Answer (score 0):

Use a callback function with `sort`.

```
player.sort(function(d){ return d.order})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var player = [{uid: 15, order: 567}, 
              {uid: 4, order: 789}, 
              {uid: 27, order: 123}, 
              {uid: 1, order: 654}];

player.sort(function(a,b){
   return a.order - b.order; 
});
```

[JSFIDDLE.](http://jsfiddle.net/ejquvfoe/)